# cmake cygwin make.exe error

Tags: makefile, cygwin, cmake

I have got a problem with CMake 2.8.9. I use the GUI.
I try to make a makefile (ogre 1.8).
As I have Windows 7 x64, I use CygWin with gcc.exe and g++.exe and make.exe (located in the bin directory).
When I try to "Configure", CMake logs the following error:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Check for working C compiler: G:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: G:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at G:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
The C compiler "G:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: H:/Ogre/gcc18/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:G:/cygwin/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec2682355191/fast"

/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2682355191.dir\build.make
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2682355191.dir/build

D e r B e f e h l " m T r y C o m p i l e E x e c 2 6 8 2 3 5 5 1 9 1 .  d i r " i s t e n t w e d e r f a l s c h g e s c h r i e b e n o d e r  k o n n t e   n i c h t   g e f u n d e n   w e r d e n . 

makeMakefile:116: recipe for target `cmTryCompileExec2682355191/fast' failed

: *** [cmTryCompileExec2682355191/fast] Error 1





CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:44 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Whereas D e r B e f e h l " m T r y C o m p i l e.......
 
means "The command "mTryCompile......" is either spelled wrong or could not be found

```
$ make -version
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

```
gcc-Version 4.5.3 (GCC)
```

My cache looks like this:

```
//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/ar.exe

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler.
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/g++.exe

//C compiler.
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds (/MD /Ob1 /Oi
// /Ot /Oy /Gs will produce slightly less optimized but smaller
// files).
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=' '

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/OGRE

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/ld.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/make.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=' '

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/nm.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/objcopy.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/objdump.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=OGRE

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/ranlib.exe

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_SH:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of dll's.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=' '

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=OFF

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=OFF

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=G:/cygwin/bin/strip.exe

//If true, cmake will use relative paths in makefiles and projects.
CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS:BOOL=ON

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF

CYGWIN:BOOL=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
OGRE_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=H:/Ogre/gcc18

//Value Computed by CMake
OGRE_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=H:/Ogre/ogre_src_v1-8-1/ogre_src_v1-8-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Cygwin you cannot use your regular Windows CMake installation. You have to install the UNIX version of CMake using the Cygwin Setup program.

Comment: Works like a charm. But I want to note here: For Windows compilation, one has to add
`CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32:UNINITIALIZED=1`
to the cmake cache file.

Comment: @MarcoAlka: ` cmake -D CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32:UNINITIALIZED=1` was an epic fail.

Comment: @Orwellophile and.... why is that? It sure solved my problem at the time.

Comment: @MarcoAlka `cmake version 3.3.2`: `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/orwellophile/CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32:UNINITIALIZED=1" does not exist.`

Comment: @Orwellophile So you comment the solution to _my_ problem with _your_own_ problem? That's not very helpful, I guess...

Comment: @MarcoAlka well it doesn't sound very nice when you put it like that!

Comment: @Orwellophile, well giving negative comments without explanation on already solved questions, which are over three years old is not very nice either... If you are unhappy with that particular answer, please feel free to post your own (maybe up2date) solution. That way you might be able to help future people with a similar problem. If you have a different question (for your version or w/e), feel free to make a new question. That being said: THANK YOU for joining the conversation and trying to improve that answer :)

Comment: Like I'm going to totally delete as many of these comments after you've read them, because like this is total embarrassment to be having this discussion.  I have totally forgotten what project it was that I needed CMAKE to work with, and the only stuff in my history relating to cmake is YouCompleteMe for vim (which is working already).  FWIW, I read the man page, and it specifies the cmake arguments as -D VARNAME:TYPE=VALUE so I'm guessing it was complaining at the lack of remaining arguments (like `--build .` for a start), and taking the option for a directory.  So my bad.